What mechanism exists, if any, for the US Republican Party to remove its presidential nominee and choose to nominate someone else?
Once the US Republican Party has selected its nominee for the US presidency and he or she has accepted the nomination, what mechanism is there, if any, for the party to remove its nomination from that person and give it to an alternative person of their choice?

Is anyone actually calling for this?

I have no idea. Why does it matter?

Why worry about speculating about something that won’t happen? Also the mechanics to replace the nominee will depend upon the reason for the replacement.

I'm not worrying. It's like asking whether there's a mechanism for the British Parliament to replace the monarch. As far as I know no-one is calling for that, but it's a fair enough question about political procedure. Can you expand on your second sentence? I'm not asking about when a Republican presidential nominee resigns or dies.

Don't forget there are 50 different states with different rules for what is required to get on and change a ballot.

I'm not sure this is actually a duplicate. The linked question refers to the situation prior to the nomination and acceptance of a candidate at the party's convention. This question focuses upon after that point in the process and effectively asks if the party as a whole can rescind their nomination.

@Pyrotechnical Perhaps, and I've voted to reopen for that reason. But they're related, because in both cases we're talking about replacing whoever won the primaries. It would only be different if someone won the primaries, some else was then nominated at the convention, and then they wanted to undo that nomination (perhaps going back to the primary winner, but it could be a third candidate).

While this is unlikely to happen with the GOP, it's almost conceivable with the Dems. Biden won the primaries, Harris is going to be nominated at the DNC, but they could still have buyer's remorse between the DNC and election.

@Barmar True, but the parties have different rules about these things, so an answer for the Republicans won't necessarily apply to the Democrats and vice versa.

There are two paths.
Path 1: Death, Resignation, or Other Condition Creating a Vacancy of the Position of Nominee.
Should the nominee become incapacitated, disinclined, or otherwise ineligible for election at any time between their nomination and the election, Rule 9 of the RNC bylaws allows for the RNC to fill that vacancy.
Path 2: Rules Change
There is not presently any rule allowing the RNC to withdraw its nomination, so to do so the RNC must first consider and approve an amendment to create such a process. If the maximum of haste is applied, this would require the proposed rules change to be submitted to the RNC's Standing Subcommittee on Rules prior to September 13th in order for it to be presented to the RNC ten days prior to the September 30th deadline specified in Rule 12.
This path is highly uncertain as the language of Rule 12 suggests that to be effective for this cycle, this rules change would need to have happened in 2022, and that any such rules change could only be effective for the 2026 election cycle.
In short, Path 2 isn't a realistic possibility to be attempted, even if it were a realistic possibility of being successful (which it is not).
